# Need help slowing down arrows minecraft 1.19

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm trying to slow down skeleton arrows in minecraft 1.19, but I can't find any command to do it. I tried giving them slowness but they can't have effects. Is there something in the nbt I can change?

Comment: Looking at the [entity data](https://minecraft.fandom.com/wiki/Arrow#Entity_data) avaliable for arrows, there only seems to be the `Motion` tag that contains the current X/Y/Z speed of the arrow. You could try to achieve something by manipulating these values.

Answer (score 1):

By decreasing the Motion values, you can get the arrow to move at any speed/direction you want.

Just a heads up though that damage is affected by speed. This means that increasing an arrow's motion values to extremely high amounts is often enough to one shot players and bosses (a mechanic that some have used to build "railguns" in survival). And although I havent tested it, decreasing an arrow's motion values would likely do the opposite, and cause it to deal almost no damage.

But anyways, by decreasing the Y motion of an arrow for example, you could decrease it's speed of descent allowing it to travel much further than normal (assuming you constantly reset the descent to the desired value) or theoretically give it infinite hangtime if you set it to 0.